# Internal Server Error when creating an FPDF using LINUX raspbian

Tags: php, linux, raspberry-pi3, fpdf, internal-server-error

I'm trying to make an PDF in raspberry-pi using FPDF, but I have this error below:

I tried renewing the permission using chmod setting it to 755,
This is my code:

```
<?php
$curDate=date("m/d/y");
$pdfDate=date("mdy");
$aveTime='';

require('fpdf.php');
//Connect to your database
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","queuingsystem");

//Create new pdf file
$pdf=new FPDF('P','pt','Letter');

//Disable automatic page break
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false);

//Add first page
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',30);
$pdf->SetX(25);
$pdf->Cell(560,100,'ENLISTMENT',0,0,'C');
$pdf->Ln(72);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',15);
$pdf->SetX(25);
$pdf->Cell(140, 20, 'Date: '. $curDate ,0, 0, 'L');


//set initial y axis position per page
$y_axis_initial = 130;
//Set Row Height
$row_height = 20;

//print column titles
$pdf->SetFillColor(0, 255, 0);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
$pdf->SetY($y_axis_initial);
$pdf->SetX(25);
$pdf->Cell(140, 20, 'Student ID', 1, 0, 'C', 1);
$pdf->Cell(140, 20, 'TimeIn', 1, 0, 'C', 1);
$pdf->Cell(140, 20, 'TimeOut', 1, 0, 'C', 1);
$pdf->Cell(140, 20, 'TimeSpent', 1, 0, 'C', 1);

$y_axis = $y_axis_initial + $row_height;

//Select the Products you want to show in your PDF file
$queryGet='select studID,TimeIn,TimeOut,TimeSpent from     tbl_enlistmentlogs WHERE date=CURDATE() AND Status=2';
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$queryGet);
$rowCount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
//initialize counter
$i = 0;

//Set maximum rows per page
$max = 25;


if($rowCount==0){
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',30);
$pdf->SetX(25);
$pdf->Cell(560,100,'No Records found!',0,0,'C');
}
else{

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
//If the current row is the last one, create new page and print     column title
if ($i == $max)
{
    $pdf->AddPage();

    //print column titles for the current page
    $pdf->SetFillColor(0, 255, 0);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
    $pdf->SetY($y_axis_initial);
    $pdf->SetX(25);
    $pdf->Cell(140, 20, 'Student ID', 1, 0, 'C', 1);
    $pdf->Cell(140, 20, 'TimeIn', 1, 0, 'C', 1);
    $pdf->Cell(140, 20, 'TimeOut', 1, 0, 'C', 1);
    $pdf->Cell(140, 20, 'TimeSpent', 1, 0, 'C', 1);

    //Go to next row
    $y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;

    //Set $i variable to 0 (first row)
    $i = 0;
}

$StudentID = $row['studID'];
$TimeIn = $row['TimeIn'];
$TimeOut = $row['TimeOut'];
$TimeSpent = $row['TimeSpent'];
$pdf->SetFillColor(232, 232, 232);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','', 12);
$pdf->SetY($y_axis);
$pdf->SetX(25);
$pdf->Cell(140, 20, $StudentID, 1, 0, 'C', 1);
$pdf->Cell(140, 20, $TimeIn, 1, 0, 'C', 1);
$pdf->Cell(140, 20, $TimeOut, 1, 0, 'C', 1);
$pdf->Cell(140, 20, $TimeSpent, 1, 0, 'C', 1);

//Go to next row
$y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;
$i = $i + 1;
}
$queryAve='SELECT SEC_TO_TIME ( AVG ( TIMESTAMPDIFF ( SECOND, `TimeIn`,`TimeOut`))) FROM tbl_enlistmentlogs WHERE date=CURDATE() AND Status=2';
$ave=mysqli_query($conn,$queryAve);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($ave);
$aveTime=$row[0];
$pdf->Ln(20);
$pdf->SetFillColor(255, 255, 0);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B', 12);
$pdf->SetX(25);
$pdf->Cell(420, 20, 'THE AVERAGE TIME SPENT BY STUDENT', 1, 0, 'C', 1);
$pdf->Cell(140, 20, $aveTime, 1, 0, 'C', 1);

}
mysqli_close($conn);
//Save file
$filee=$pdf->Output('EnlistmentReport'.$pdfDate.'.pdf','F');
$pdf->Output();

?>
```

This is the error provided by the error.log.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Some data has
>   already been output, can't send PDF file in
>   /var/www/html/fpdf.php:271\nStack trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/html/fpdf.php(1063): FPDF->Error('Some data has a...')\n#1
>   /var/www/html/fpdf.php(999): FPDF->_checkoutput()\n#2
>   /var/www/html/testFpdf.php(116): FPDF->Output()\n#3 {main}\n
>   thrown in /var/www/html/fpdf.php on line 271

In windows it will preview a pdf file without any error.

Comment: Hi, that is the actual error provided by /var/www/apache2/error.log. 
The error is when i include the "$pdf->Output();" code in my php file.
I did it first on my desktop using Windows OS, it successfully made a pdf preview and has no errors. That error shows on my RPI. Thanks.

Comment: please - show us _the code_. not just the one line, but everything surrounding it. and **edit** your post to do so.

Comment: I just edited it thanks

Comment: I already solved it by adding "ob_clean();" in fpdf file. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Gaboo - I rolled back the SOLVED edit. Please place answers in Answer blocks. Later, you can accept your own Answer. Also see [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/173448) (I retracted my Close Votes a couple of days ago, after you added your code. A solution that fixes the problem will likely be Upvote worthy. But we need a first class answer to upvote).